# Defining a variable to be greater than zero

Tags: variable

I am trying to do some integrals over a region , however this region is going to depend on parameters $ \alpha , \beta $ and when calculating these integrals they give multiple values depending if $\alpha , \beta$ are greater or not than $0$. Is  there anyway i can define a-prior that my variable is greater than zero so this doesn't keep happening? Thanks in advance.

Imagine , my problem is that i want to calculate an integral with respect to a variable $\alpha$ but this gives me numerous options and i want the value when $\alpha$ is greater than $0$ is there anyway i can predefine this variable $\alpha$ to be greater than zero so that the integral just gives me the value that i want ?

Also if i am working with multiple variables say for example $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is there anyway i can define that the first one is always smaller than the second so it doenst affect my calculations in the future?

Comment: Have you looked at "Element"?  The fifth example shows integrating over a region using Element to specify the domain.

Comment: Yeah that helps, do i know how i can write that i want the variable greater than zero, if writing the interval works?

Comment: Please show your attempt at a solution (that isn't working) and I can see about suggesting where you might be able to use Element.

Comment: I tried doing element , and then writting the interval from $0$ to $\infty$ but that didnt really work.